# Making a measurement converter C++

Tags: c++

My instructor asks for me to make a measurement tool in cups with outputs of equivalent gallons, quarts, pints, etc.

The program is to store constant's that will be used to calculate the conversions.
The output will list a table.

I'm stumped on where to start.  Any suggestions?

---

Alright, so I've got a converter figured out, however I'm putting the new line in the wrong spot and can't seem to figure out where it goes.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
float cups, gallons, quarts, pints, tablespoons, teaspoons;

std:: cout << "Please input the value in cups";
std:: cin >> cups;
gallons = cups * .0625;
quarts = cups * .25;
pints = cups * .5;
tablespoons = cups * 16;
teaspoons = cups * 48;

std:: cout << "The number of gallons is ";
std:: cout<<gallons"\n";   
std:: cout << "The number of quarts is ";
std:: cout<<quarts"\n";
std:: cout << "The number of pints is ";
std:: cout<<pints "\n";
std:: cout << "The number of tablespoons is ";
std:: cout<<tablespoons "\n";
std:: cout << "The number of teaspoons is ";
std:: cout<<teaspoons"\n";

return 0;
}
```

This is what I have and it works without my \n additions which cause syntax error.

---

OK so I figured it out, and this is my final product, ran smoothly and looks great. Thanks everyone for the help!

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
float cups, gallons, quarts, pints, tablespoons, teaspoons;

std:: cout << "Please input the value in cups to be converted";
std:: cin >> cups;
gallons = cups * .0625;
quarts = cups * .25;
pints = cups * .5;
tablespoons = cups * 16;
teaspoons = cups * 48;

std:: cout << "That many cups is equal to ";
cout<<"\n";
std:: cout << "Gallons ";
std:: cout<<gallons;
cout<<"\n";
std:: cout << "Quarts ";
std:: cout<<quarts;
cout<<"\n";
std:: cout << "Pints ";
std:: cout<<pints;
cout<<"\n";
std:: cout << "Tablespoons ";
std:: cout<<tablespoons;
cout<<"\n";
std:: cout << "Teaspoons ";
std:: cout<<teaspoons;


return 0;
}
```

Comment: First, search the internet for examples.  Probably something like "c++ measurement conversion example"

Comment: Let the use input a number and then output that number multiplied by 1.5.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."

Comment: I've done some changes and figured out what I need to, but I'm putting my new line \n in the wrong spot. Where should it go to avoid syntax error? Putting the code in the initial post.

Comment: Nevermind figured it out, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Start with HelloWorld.

When that works perfectly, you can pursue input and conversion+output as two independent goals.

For input, write a function that will take a number of cups from the user.

For conversion+output, write a function that converts cups to gallons and prints the result. When that works perfectly, add code for quarts, then pints, and so on. Implement conversion factors as `const` variables.

When both of these functions work perfectly, hook them together, test the result and you're done.

Comment: Thank you for the instruction, I didn't quite understand what you meant so I researched what you were talking about and have made great progress. Thank you.